# How to write negative query to MarkLogic with Java API

Tags: java, marklogic

I'm trying to search for json documents which does not contain field "status" but I'm still getting wrong results.

I wrote XQuery code that works in MarkLogic terminal:

```
cts:search(
 fn:doc(),
 cts:not-query(
  cts:json-property-scope-query(
  "status",
  cts:true-query())))
```

And I wanted to achieve similiar thing using Java API, but I don't have **jsonPropertyScopeQuery** method in **StructuredQueryBuilder** class. So I tried to write a bit longer query using **queryBuilder.not()** which would look for every document that doesn't have EDITING, CORRECTING or ACCEPTING status (those are the only statuses that document might have). I hoped that would return result I expect but still I'm getting all the documents.

Here's how my **queryBuilder.not()** for EDITING status looks like:

```
var notContains = queryBuilder.not(
                    queryBuilder.word(queryBuilder.jsonProperty("status"), "EDITING"));
```

I'm using maven com.marklogic version 6.1.0.
Version of Database is: 10.0-7.3

Comment: Why are you wrapping the jsonProperty query in a word query?

Comment: Without queryBuilder.not jsonProperty wrapped in word query works fine - it returns document with EDITING status

Comment: Please open an issue for this at https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/issues - that will keep it on our radar, and we should be able to either provide a working example there or track a fix for a release.